# Why am I unable to get docstring printed out using sphinx python package?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, python-decorators, docstring

I am using Sphinx to document out my functions. However, it does not read my doc strings for function with a decorator.
Sphinx just replace the function doc strings with `<The magic happens here>`

My functions are written in this manner with a decorator. How do i make Sphinx detect the doc strings in the function.

Folder is in this format

- Project

  - Functions
    - function.py

    - docs

```
def wrap(pre, post):
    """ Wrapper """

    def decorate(func):
        """ Decorator """

        def call(*args, **kwargs):
            """ The magic happens here """
            pre(func)
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            post(func)
            return result
        return call
    return decorate

def entering(func, *args):
    """ Pre function logging """
    logging.debug("Entered {}".format(func.__name__))
    # logging.info(func.__doc__)
    logging.debug("Function at line {} in {}".format(func.__code__.co_firstlineno, func.__code__.co_filename))
    try:
        logging.debug("The argument {} is {}".format(func.__code__.co_varnames[0], *args))
    except IndexError:
        logging.debug("No arguments")


def exiting(func):
    """ Post function logging """
    logging.debug("Exited {}".format(func.__name__))

@wrap(entering, exiting)
def function(a, b):
    """
    Function to execute
    :param a:
    :param b:
    :return: Sum of a+b
    """
    return a+b
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. i have correct the indentation. it is properly indented in my function. Yes, it just output The magic happens here.

Comment: apologies. is a function call wrap. edited.

Comment: i have added the two functions. basically, it's just to keep track of the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your `decorate` function to copy the docstring from `func` onto `call` before returning it. Otherwise Sphinx can only get the docstring of `call`, not the docstring of the original function.

You can do this yourself by directly doing `call.__doc__ = func.__doc__`, or you could use the `functools.wraps` decorator from the standard library to do it for you (which also copies a few other attributes by default, and can be customized quite a bit).

I'd try:

```
import functools

def wrap(pre, post):
    """ Wrapper """

    def decorate(func):
        """ Decorator """

        @functools.wraps(func)              # this copies over the docstring and more
        def call(*args, **kwargs):
            """ The magic happens here """
            pre(func)
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            post(func)
            return result
        return call
    return decorate
```

Comment: It works! Thanks for sharing! Appreciate it!